# Error al instalar Android SDK en Macbook M1

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

Reciente instalando Android estudio en la parte de la descarga de los paquetes, me salió el siguiente error, alguna solución?

```
An error occurred while trying to compute required packages.
```

[image: An error occurred while trying to compute required packages.]

Comment: Esto puede tener distintas causas, te sugerimos agregar mas información, revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigando encontre esta respuesta [Link de la respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69903685/8207243)

Basicamente nos descargamos ***IntelliJ IDEA Community***:
[Link de descarga](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=mac)

Creamos un nuevo proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Damos click en instalar SDK

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siguiente, Siguiente, Siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez terminado, abrimos android studio y empezará a descargar los componentes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Listo, android funcionando.

Comment: Hola, estas preguntando inicialmente sobre Android Studio  y pones una respuesta sobre Intellij Idea?  Te sugerimos revisar [asnwer], saludos.